# Why rlwrap clutters the screen with redundant output?

Tags: sql, linux, sqlplus, rlwrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why rlwrap echos “redundantly” what I type from the keyboard ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485129/why-rlwrap-echos-redundantly-what-i-type-from-the-keyboard)

I am using the rlwrap utility under linux for command line editing while using sql*plus. Everything is fine except that the utility echoes every command I enter from the keyboard. For example suppose that I typed this statement in the prompt:

```
SQL> select last_name from employees
```

the same statement would be echoed again in the terminal making the output looks like:

```
SQL> select last_name from employees
select last_name from employees
```

then when I complete the select statement on the next line, the output would look like:

```
SQL> select last_name from employees
select last_name from employees
2 where department_id = 100;
where department_id = 100;
```

The problem is, with larger queries, this redundancy will clutter the terminal making the query hard to read, so any suggestions to suppress the unnecessary output would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why repost?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485129/why-rlwrap-echos-redundantly-what-i-type-from-the-keyboard

Comment: Do not post duplicates; proper tagging should help but be patient.

Comment: Please edit the original instead of posting a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rlwap, I'd use [SQLPlus' SPOOL directive](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/spool.html) to save output to a file.  Depending on the complexity, might want to script the query/queries to file first...

Didn't know this was a dupe question - copy/pasted to original.